# Change object data

Tags: javascript, node.js, object

I have this text file (800kb [url](https://gyazo.com/0a8633dfbd6170e1c73c2ecf274176e7)) inwhich a some JSON data is stored. After I load the data from the text file I would like to change stuff and loop over it.

I did this using this sample simple function;

```
var convertPriceFormat = function(content){
  var obj = {};

  for(var appid in content){

    var gameEntry = content[appid];

    for(var hashName in gameEntry){
      var entry = gameEntry[hashName];
      obj[hashName] = entry.price;
    };

    console.log(Object.keys(gameEntry).length);
  };

  return obj;
}
```

There's four sub-objects in the returned object ofwhich they all have about `3000` entries, that's not like a huge amount.

All data per entry is structuated like so;

```
'Pinstripe Suit Jacket': { 
                           average_price: 0.02,
                           listings: 11,
                           volume: 1185.03,
                           price: 0.03 
}
```

Problem is; for some odd reason when I log the length of the gameEntry (so the total of entries per sub-object), there's like 12 seconds between the first log and the second log.

Why is this?

Load time (relative since start, numbers are the amount of entries it had to loop over):

```
2373 '3.48s'
5769 '24.422s'
1405 '25.326s'
641 '25.436s'
```

Comment: Does it also take 12 seconds for the first log to show up?

Comment: @ack_inc about like 5 seconds since the server is started, the last 2 are nearly instant, they both have <1500 entries. the first has about 3500 and the second about 5000.

Comment: I'd say `content[appid]` is costy in this case as there are 3000 entries in the object, but 12 secondes is too much.

Comment: Could you try to use `var appid of Object.keys(content)` and same with `gameEntry` instead? My only guess is that `in` loops over other properties as well.

Comment: @jhp tried just now, also logged how many seconds it takes before it shows the last line.

It's giving me the same results. Check post for price since start per entry.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the entry does not really look like what you think it does. Try this code or a variant of it to  trace what is going on.

```js
var convertPriceFormat = function(content) {
  var obj = {};

  for (var appid in content) {
    console.log(`appid: ${appid}`)

    var gameEntry = content[appid];

    for (var hashName in gameEntry) {
        console.log(`hashName: ${hashName}`)

      var entry = gameEntry[hashName];
      obj[hashName] = entry.price;
    };

    console.log(Object.keys(gameEntry).length);
  };

  return obj;
}

const entry1 = {
  'Pinstripe Suit Jacket': {
    average_price: 0.02,
    listings: 11,
    volume: 1185.03,
    price: 0.03
  }
}

const entries = []

for (let i = 0; i < 3000; i++) {
  entries.push(entry1)
}

console.log(`Number of entries: ${entries.length}`)

convertPriceFormat(entries.slice(0,3))
```

Comment: I copied the function (did you even change anything) and got a new result of about 0.002s - 0.016s per appid. What did you change if I may ask?

Comment: In this example, it only processes a few entries, see "entries.slice(0,3)". The important thing is we are now logging inside your loops, additionally we can share the same code using the "Run code snippet" to get a better idea of what is going on.

Comment: @Borda, where did you get to on this.

Answer (score 0):

use hasOwnProperty to filter for in loop.

```
var convertPriceFormat = function (content) {
    var obj = {};
    for (var appid in content) {
        var gameEntry = content[appid];
        for (var hashName in gameEntry) {
            var entry = gameEntry[hashName];
            obj[hashName] = entry.price;
        };
    };
    return obj;
}

var convertPriceFormat2 = function (content) {
    var obj = {};
    for (var appid in content) {
        if (content.hasOwnProperty(appid)) {
            var gameEntry = content[appid];
            for (var hashName in gameEntry) {
                if (gameEntry.hasOwnProperty(hashName)) {
                    var entry = gameEntry[hashName];
                    obj[hashName] = entry.price;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return obj;
}

const entry1 = {
    'Pinstripe Suit Jacket': {
        average_price: 0.02,
        listings: 11,
        volume: 1185.03,
        price: 0.03
    }
}

const entries = []

for (let i = 0; i < 3000; i++) {
    entries.push(entry1)
}

console.log(`Number of entries: ${entries.length}`)

console.time("time")
convertPriceFormat(entries)
console.timeEnd("time")

console.time("time2")
convertPriceFormat2(entries)
console.timeEnd("time2")
```

results are better in avarage

[image: ss]